# Passing strings in a lambda function

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I would like to automate the following code line:

```
df_b = df_b.append([{'A':df_a['A'][1], 'B':df_a['B'][1], 'C':df_a['C'][1]}], ignore_index=True)
```

and I was considering using a lambda function to do so:

```
list = ['A', 'B', 'C']
func = lambda j: df_a[j][1]
df_b = df_b.append([{(func(list))}], ignore_index=True)
```

And I got the following error:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2896             try:
-> 2897                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2898             except KeyError:

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 1
```

What would be your advice to run such a lambda function?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want here is a dictionary comprehension:

```
lst = ['A', 'B', 'C']
func = lambda j: df_a[j][1]
to_append = {s:func(s) for s in lst}
df_b = df_b.append([to_append], ignore_index=True)
```

As a side note, you could equally define `func` with a `def` instead of `lambda` in this case.

Comment: Your answer is OK, but the lambda function is so trivial here that it would be clearer to directly implement its content in the dictionnary comprehension.